# Web for teaching how to use the mouse for super-beginners

Tags: mouse, documentation

I remember there was a mouse use teaching application on the Macintosh 128k computers. It was something about a city and it guided you about how to click, double click, etc...

Does it exist something similar (web or application) for any OS?

There are still some people (older people in particular) which would like to get introduced into computers, and the use of a mouse is quite difficult...

Comment: There is a similar program that comes with Windows 3, if you come across a copy, you can run it in (Dosbox)[http://www.dosbox.com/]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **[Mouse Trainer](http://www.rekenwonder.com/mousetrainer.htm)** will quickly train any novice user to use the
>   mouse. It is ideal for computer
>   training centres and workshops. In
>   about 60 minutes time, a novice
>   computer user can become acquainted
>   with clicking, double-clicking and
>   dragging, without the intervention of
>   a supervisor.

[image]

Multi-lingual, works with Windows 95/98/Me/NT/2000/XP/Vista

*Mouse Trainer is freeware.*

> **[Basics 4 Beginners Mouse Tutorial](http://www.basics4beginners.com/site/MouseTutorial.aspx)** helps you master basic
>   computer mouse skills including copy
>   and paste, drag and drop, and double
>   click.

[image]

*Basics 4 Beginners Mouse Tutorial is freeware.*

Online tutorials:

**[Mousercize](http://www.hcplibrary.org/childrens/Programs/Mousercise/Mousercize/mousercizeindex.htm)** is an interactive short how-to-use-a-mouse tutorial.

**[Mousing Around](http://www.pbclibrary.org/mousing/intro.htm)** is a tutorial to use a mouse to interact with a computer